# Big Margin on the Right

Tags: html, css, viewport

How can I get rid of the margin right? I don't know where it came from.

Here is my sample code. Please see attached screenshot.[image]

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=425" />

html body {
width: 425px;
height: auto;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Try this instead: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: i need to specify a value on the content.. Is there another solution? because it only occurs on ios but not on android

Comment: If you use the meta element in my last comment, does it fix the layout in iOS? Just to know if we've pinpointed the problem.

Comment: yes, but it ruins my design because it's not responsive.. i just want to fit my design(425px) in all mobile devices..

Comment: [**A pixel is not a pixel**](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html) and [**A pixel is not a pixel**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#A_pixel_is_not_a_pixel) :-)

Comment: by the way its only on the ios that has a margin on right.. i wonder why

Comment: That's why I posted those articles for you. Read about Apple devices and pixel display.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a comma beween html and body

```
html, body {
width: 425px;
height: auto;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```